# Where in on a list of string in sqlite 3

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am training a ML model on a huge dataset. I have converted the CSV to a SQL database. But, I have encountered a problem in correctly retrieving data for each batch.

```
custs= #list of 1000 customers
df=pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE cust_id IN (%s)'% (",".join(map(str,custs))) ,con=disk_engine)
```

This gives me all the records of the customers. But, say, if I want only last three transactions of a customer.

```
months= #list containing the required months, custs= #each cust_id is repeated thrice 
df=pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE cust_id IN (%s) AND month IN (%s)'
                         % (",".join(map(str,custs)),",".join(map(str,months))) ,con=disk_engine)
```

This doesn't work because the AND statement is applied to whole list. Therefore, I created a new column which is a string combination of customer_id and month and this key is unique for each record.

```
key= #str(cust_id) +'_'+ str(month)
```

I can't use the join statement for a list of keys. What method will work here? I tried to use placeholders here but since I am new to SQL, I didn't make much progress.

EDIT

The data has 116 columns. 113 of them are modelling variables and there is a DV column. The other two columns are `cust_id` and `month`. The data is for 8 months and each customer has 1 or 0 transactions per month. Therefore, a customer might have transactions ranging from 1 to 8 in the database.

For training a batch I pick 1000 customers and a month at random from a list in memory . For example if I picked list contains `cust_id=1` and `month=4`, then I need transaction for month `[2,3,4]` for this customer. For `cust_id=20` and `month=2` I'll use `[1,1,2]` If a transaction is missing then also I pad with the last transaction.

Comment: Could you provide all of the columns you have in the table? One option would be to use `row_number` or `rank` to filter the desired rows, but it would only really make sense in this case if there was a date field (for sorting).

Comment: @pault, the data  has 116 varaibles out of which 113 are modelling variables, 1 DV and the other two columns are month and cust_id. Sorting can be done on the month column

Comment: If two transactions happen in the same month, how do you sort them?

Comment: Will sorting on both cust_id and month help? Can you explain why is sorting required?

Comment: You said you want to get the _last_ three transactions for each customer. I'm asking how you define the last three. Is there only one transaction per month per customer?

Comment: I think it may help to focus on the SQL query. 

`"SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE cust_id IN '{0}' AND month IN '{1}' ORDER BY transaction_id DESC LIMIT 3".format(cust_id, month)`.

As we don't know what columns are in your table, I guessed.

Comment: @pault yes there is only one transaction per customer per month

Comment: Evan, the this query gives me the last three records of one customer only

Comment: You should be able to this using `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()`. I don't have access to a database at the moment, but I think this would be something like: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY month DESC) AS row FROM transactions WHERE cust_id in '{0}') A WHERE row <=3`